# Autocomplete using bootstrap typehead working fine but i need corresponding value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, typeahead.js

Working on bootstrap typehead for autocomplete. With the help of the typehead documentation the autocomplete working fine but when I select the particular value from autocomplete i need to get the relevant name in the label field.

This is my HTML code.

```
 <input type="text" class="ipt_Field" id="txt_schName" name="txt_schName" />
 <label id="school_Name"></label>
```

This is my json data

```
["COL000001,Emirates College of Technology- UAE","COL000002,Al Khawarizmi International College- UAE","COL000003,Syscoms College","COL000004,Abounajm Khanj Pre-Uni Center","COL000005,Advanced Placement","COL000006,Al Buraimi College (Uni Clge)","COL000007,Al-Ain Community College","COL000008,AMA Computer College","COL000009,Arab Academy for Bankg and Fin","COL0000010,ARABACDSCITECHMARTIMETRNS","COL0000011,Arapahoe Community College"]
```

This is my jquery code

```
    $("#txt_schName").typeahead({
        name: 'School Name',
        // data source
        prefetch: 'json/school_name.json',
        // max item numbers list in the dropdown
        limit: 5,
        minLength:3        
});
```

Kindly please guide me how to get the corresponding vaule to the label. I am struggling lot.

Thanks & Regards
Mahadevan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep a simple key / value pair, split-up your data into an array of objects.
For example:

```
var aData = [{
    "iso": "DE",
    "desc" : "Germany"
}, {
    "iso": "FR",
    "desc" : "France"
}, {
    "iso": "CA",
    "desc" : "Canada"
}, {
    "iso": "NO",
    "desc" : "Norway"
}];
```

Configure your typeahead.js as follows

```
$(function () {
    var bhData = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("desc"),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: aData
    });


    $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'countrylist',
        display: 'desc',
        limit: 50,
        source: bhData,
        templates: {
            empty: ['<div class="empty-message">', 'unable to find country', '</div>'].join('\n'),
            suggestion: function (data) {
                return '<p><strong>' + data.iso + '</strong>&#160;' + data.desc + '</p>';
            }
        }
    });

// Capture selected event and output the selected key / value data
        $('.typeahead').on('typeahead:selected', function (event, data) {       
                $("#iso").html( data.iso );                                        
                $("#desc").html( data.desc );
        });

    });
```

Here's a link to a full working example https://jsfiddle.net/W_Walseth/uL4Lkmdt/4/

Comment: thanks for the effort but the autocomplete was not working

Comment: Sorry I didn't link to the typeahead bundle with https.  Try this link http://jsfiddle.net/W_Walseth/uL4Lkmdt/4/